# 9patch image looks blurry

Tags: android

I want to use 9patch image,but it's looking blurry in device.Here you can see:

[image]

You can see edges are blurry.

This is my goal:

[image]

And this is my 9patch image:

[image]

You can see,it's looking big and blurry in device.This is my xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="dfgdfgdf"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mes3" />
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the black border on the left side, just to the left of the "arrow" pointing left and also along the bottom where you have that shadow.  The black bars on the left and top are telling the UI what parts can be stretched, so that's why they are being stretched and look blurry.

Comment: I did like this:http://oi62.tinypic.com/kebtbb.jpg  Result: http://prntscr.com/4s0fsw  Arrow is still blurry.What is wrong with it ?

Comment: Make sure you are placing the assets in the correct drawable directory for the density it is intended.  If the default density is xhdpi, it should go there.  It looks as though it has been placed in "drawable" but is being used on a higher density device, so the image is being upscaled before stretching.

Comment: Thank you,it's looking good now.I dragged to xhdpi folder because I am testing on Galaxy s5.But what should I do for mdpi,hdpi,ldpi etc. devices ? I don't know exactly what should I do an adjusment on this image for other devices ?

Comment: For lower density screens you *should* be ok as scaling down doesn't look nearly as bad as scaling up.  However, if you want to be exact you'll need to provide separate assets for the different densities.  The DPI calculations aren't difficult, basically mdpi = 160dpi screen so you have to apply a conversion factor.  Rather than do it manually, there are some online tools available, such as this one: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

Comment: I checked now this link,My background image width is 21px on xhdpi.Calculator says 21px in xhdpi = 15.75px in hdpi,so if I create one more background image and set width value to 15.75px then drag to hdpi folder is enough ?

Comment: Yes, if you re-sample your image so that it is about 16px and put it in the hdpi folder that will be used on hdpi devices.  For many images this shouldn't be needed as the down sampled xhdpi version should still look good on hdpi.  You could fire up an emulator set with hdpi to verify before creating new assets.

Comment: Thank you so much,I understood the logic :)