# Android: Why is my background image of the layout zoomed in and blurred?

Tags: android, xml

I'm making an easy chatting app and I made a `.9.png` pic as the speech bubble. Here's a part of the message item layout XML (*the bubble sent by user*):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_send">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The **`@drawable/bg_send`** is a 102px*102px `.9.png` file at `app\res\`. I thought it should be small displaying on my 5" 1920*1080 phone. But it's bigger than it should be and that caused blurring.

[image: This pic is 1:1]

What should I do if I want to make it as I wish?

Comment: Does it help if you remove the `layout_margin` on your `TextView`? **Edit:** Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130479/9patch-image-looks-blurry) answer may be useful.

Comment: how many `drawable` folder ??

Comment: Put this image in all drawable folder available in res folder and check it.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya  At first, there's only one folder. Then I create `hdpi`, `mdpi`, `xdpi` and so on and put this image in all of them but it still doesn't help.

Comment: @bhaveshN I tried putting them into `hdpi`, `mdpi`, `xdpi`, `xxdpi`, `xxxdpi`. It remains the same.

Comment: @PPartisan Thanks. I tried removing `layout_margin` and it doesn't help. And I guess there's nothing wrong with my nine-patch png because I only set 1px black point on the top and left sides, and the stretch works right when there's a large body of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using .9.png use the drawable images instead. Here is the xml code that will fulfill your requirement.

**res/drawable/bg_textview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#607D8B"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Thank you so much~ This approach solved my problem even better than I expected!

Comment: @AlexFan please accept an answer if it helps to solve your problem. It will be helpful for others. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The image stretches to the size of of your LinearLayout (for which it is the background). The margin around the TextView makes the LinearLayout bigger. Move the `android:layout_margin="10dp"` attribute to the LinearLayout to have a margin around the bubble.

Comment: Sadly I tried that and it still doesn't work. And even when there's no text inside and the image is not stretched (a round) it is also bigger and blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/right_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_send"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"/>
```

Good luck